# c++ - proper way to add function to separate file

Tags: c++

I know this should be easy, but I can't seem to grasp it.  All I want to do is be able to use getUTC() function in my main.cpp file.  This is obviously wrong, but I have it there to show what I am trying to do.  Be kind - newbie to c++.

My understanding is the 'correct' way to build a project is to have separate 'parts' of the code in their own file, much like any other language I am used to, as you can view/edit easier down the road. So like in this case mylib would be my common functions used throughout my project.  In another header/file might be all my file handling and so on.

main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include "mylib.h"
using namespace mylib;

mylib::getUTC();
```

mylib.h

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

namespace mylib
{
    void getUTC();
}

#endif
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include <ctime>

namespace mylib
{
    void getUTC() {
        time_t utcTime;
        return time(&utcTime);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE EDIT:**

mylib.h

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

namespace mylib
{
    time_t getUTC();
}

#endif
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include <ctime>

namespace mylib
{
    time_t getUTC() {
        time_t utcTime;
        return time(&utcTime);
    }

}
```

Then in main.cpp I can just call it like `mylib::getUTC()`.  This compiles and works.  One of you mentioned getting rid of the `namespace mylib`, but as I will have quite a few functions in this file not to mention will probably end up with more header/cpp files for use in my main.cpp I think this is a great way to differentiate my code/sections unless there is some reason that should not be done?

Also, it is pretty obvious to me now how this is done... not sure why I was getting confused.  I have a pretty solid background in different languages just not C++ so as I begin to play around with code one of my main concerns is to make sure I am going about it the 'correct/proper' way so it doesn't bite me down the road such as using multiple header/source files.

**MORE UPDATES:**

I guess maybe it didn't work after all.  Getting these errors when compiling :

```
Error   C2086   'int mylib::time_t': redefinition mylib.cpp
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) mylib.cpp
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int mylib.cpp
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int mylib.h 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{' mylib.cpp
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'getUTC' mylib.cpp
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'getUTC' mylib.h
```

Comment: why do u think this is wrong?? what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

You  have the basic idea.  Essentially you compile separate .cpp files into .o or object files.  Then you link all of your .o files together into an executable.  One of the .cpp file should contain the `main` function.

I see two problems with your code:

1. Your main.cpp file does not contain a main function.  You probably
   want to put your single line of code inside a main function.
2. You function is void and yet you are returning something from it.  In order to return something from your function, it should have a return type in both it's declaration and definition.

Comment: 1 - Yes, I know I didn't include the whole main file this was just an example. 2 - Can you be more specific?  That is where I am not understanding what is needed - I think I am just overthinking the whole thing.

Comment: Getting a lot of errors with that and it won't compile. Using VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is ok, but you can get rid of the using namespace line, because you have "fully qualified" four function call, put the namespace in front of the function name.

Also you might want to look at using classes, that's one of the main features of c++.

And looking back at the code you might want to change the return type of you function or it won't compile.

I'm not sure if I have misread what your intention was were you have written in main.cpp but you don't need to declare the function again, you have done that by #including the header file.